# Stretch swipe tabs width to fill whole space

Tags: android, tabs, height, size, width

is there any way of stretching tabs width (and also if possible, way of changing their height) in Android Swipe Tabs in portrait mode, when using support library?
Currently setting:

```
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">90dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">90dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>

<style name="MyActionBarTab"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:height">90dp</item>
</style>
```

In styles did not help. Also creating custom view, dynamically, with parameters of min width and height:

```
    // Tab B
    LinearLayout lila_b = new LinearLayout(this);
    lila_b.setMinimumHeight(300);
    lila_b.setMinimumHeight(300);
    lila_b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc600"));
    lila_b.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    lila_b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ImageView imvi_b = new ImageView(this);
    imvi_b.setImageResource(R.drawable.tabs_history);
    imvi_b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imvi_b.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    lila_b.addView(imvi_b);
    TextView tevi_b = new TextView(this);
    tevi_b.setText(getString(R.string.main_history));
    tevi_b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tevi_b.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tevi_b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    lila_b.addView(tevi_b);
    Tab newTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this);
    newTab.setCustomView(lila);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(historyTab);
```

Did not help.
Even this:

```
    final View tabView = actionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
    final View tabContainerView = (View) tabView.getParent();
    tabView.setMinimumHeight(300);
    tabContainerView.setMinimumHeight(300);
```

Didn't do anything. I am out of ideas.
Any solutions how to extend those tabs?

P.S. Question is about Google Support Library and Swipe Tabs. I'm not interested currently in using third party libraries...

Comment: Ok, adding <dimen name="abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width">1000dp</dimen> in my dimens did actually help with width, they are streatchen finally on whole screen. What about height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally!
Simple adding:

```
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width">1000dp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height">408dp</dimen>
```

In dimens forced tabs to stretch, horizontally and vertically. Finally there are two tabs and they are filling all space from left to right on tablet. Taht's what I need.